# Determine if comma separated values are valid using regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a string with comma separated alphanumeric values. The values are considered valid if they are exactly 2 characters in length, and if they have at least 1 alphabetical character. If all the values are valid then I would like to "capture" the entire string including commas. If a value is missing (back to back commas) then the entire string is invalid. I can only use Regex for this. Whitespace is ignored, the programming language used is Java

### Examples

- "3F, 4B, AA, A4B" - not captured because 'A4B' is length 3
- "3F, 4B, 55, A4" - not captured because '55' does not have at least 1
  alphabetical char
- "3F, 4B,," - not captured because missing value between 2nd and 3rd
  comma
- "3F, 4B, AA, A" - not captured because 'A' value is length 1
- "3F, 4B, AA," - captured (trailing comma allowed)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please show the code that you have written, where you are stuck, what you expected to happen at that point and what actually happens.

Comment: Ah I will make sure to add attempts and issues I had in the future, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just brute force this one using the following expression

```
((\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]\d),\s)*(\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]\d),?$
```

Heres a breakdown:

In your case theres 2 characters which have 3 specific cases where they are valid

```
\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]\d
    - \d[A-Z] - digit followed by uppercase A-Z characters
    - [A-Z]{2} - 2 uppercase A-Z characters
    - [A-Z]\d - uppercase A-Z character followed by a digit
```

Then using that as a base I made an expression which said I need that set of cases to be followed by a comma and a space 0 or more times

```
(                               - start group
    (\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]\d)  - group as explained above
    ,\s                         - followed by comma and space
)*                              - entire group 0 or more times
```

Then I followed that with the same expression but added some additional modifiers to it

```
(                               - start group
     \d[A-Z]|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]\d   - group as explained above
)                               - end group
,?                              - 0 or 1 trailing comma
$                               - match end of line
```

Theres probably a more elegant way of doing this expression but this way seems pretty straight forward. Heres some java examples of it in use.

```
String expression = "((\\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]\\d),\\s)*(\\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]\\d),?$";

System.out.println("3F, 4B, AA, A4B".matches(expression)); // false
System.out.println("3F, 4B, 55, A4".matches(expression)); // false
System.out.println("3F, 4B, 5A, A4".matches(expression)); // true
System.out.println("3F, 4B,,".matches(expression)); // false
System.out.println("3F, 4B, AA, A".matches(expression)); // false
System.out.println("3F, 4B, AA,".matches(expression)); // true
```

---

Theres alot of really good websites which let you test regex in your browser and get feedback immediately. This is a great way to build and test a regex and many times theres even a nice explanation peice on the page telling you about the expression you wrote.

Although many of these websites do not offer a Java enviroment for expression evaluation most languages have the same or very close to the same specification for regular expressions. To build this expression i tested it in Javascript then ran it in java to make sure it worked. Heres a link to the saved expression so you can test it yourself https://regex101.com/r/uP4oY2/1

Answer (score 2):

First, you could simplify the valid format to [Alpha+Digit][Alpha] OR [Alpha][Alpha+Digit]:

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z]"
```

Then you want to allow any number of whitespace around it:

```
String regex = "\\s*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z])\\s*"
```

And you want it to be followed by a comma, unless it's the end of the string:

```
String regex = "\\s*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z])\\s*(,|$)"
```

And this pattern can repeat any number of times (one or more):

```
String regex = "(\\s*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z])\\s*(,|$))+"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try following regex:

```
^((\s+)??(\d[a-z]|[a-z]\d|[a-z]{2}),?)+?$
```

This regex can be used in java as

```
boolean foundMatch = text.matches("(?ismd)^((\\s+)??(\\d[a-z]|[a-z]\\d|[a-z]{2}),?)+?$");
```

Test cases:

```
3F, 4B, AA, C5              // true
3F, 4B, AA, C5,             // true
3F, 4B, AA, C5,,            // false
3F, 4B, A, C5               // false
3F, 4B, AA, C5, 45, A4B     // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the idea is to have three groups connected with or

```
(Alpha Digit or Digit Alpha or Alpha Alpha)
```

Then we will allow whitespaces at the ends

```
whitespace zero or more (Alpha Digit or Digit Alpha or Alpha Alpha) whitespace zero or more
```

And last, we will repeat this 4 times with commas in between.